# jquery on ready keypressed

Tags: jquery, ajax, keypress

My page have elements loaded with ajax, i need use enter to go next input, textarea or select.
some inputs have a function to format numbers but the solution above run more that once.

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(){
    var inputs = $('input, select, textarea').on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        if ($(this).attr('data-format')) {
            formatNumber($(this));
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(this) + 1);
        if (nextInput) {
            nextInput.focus();
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: If these elements are appended dynamically on the response of an AJAX request you need to use event delegation.

Comment: You're binding a keypress handler to every input, select, and textarea every time the user presses a key. Why are you doing the nested handler binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rory and Jason mentioned, you're probably looking for event delegation.  This will allow any new inputs that didn't initially exist still respond to the keypress event once they appear.  Here's a good article on the subject: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ and your code should look something like this:

**UPDATE:**

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input, select, textarea', function(e){

  var inputs = $("input, select, textarea");

  if (e.which == 13) {
    if($(this).attr('data-format')){
      formatNumber($(this));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(this) + 1);
    if (nextInput) {
      nextInput.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: But i need get all inputs in array inputs

Comment: Updated to address the inputs array.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$(document).on('keypress',function(){
var inputs = $('input, select, textarea').one("keypress",function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    if($(this).attr('data-format')){
        formatNumber($(this));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextInput = inputs.get(inputs.index(this) + 1);
    if (nextInput) {
      nextInput.focus();
    }
  }
});
```

});

Comment: I don't think that's the solution you want. You're still binding handlers in handlers.